# Can an outside query modify a document involved in an ongoing transaction?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, transactions, nosql, aggregation-framework

```
  const client = new MongoClient(uri);
  await client.connect();
  await client
    .db('mydb1')
    .collection('foo');
  const session = client.startSession();
  const transactionOptions = {
    readPreference: 'primary',
    readConcern: { level: 'local' },
    writeConcern: { w: 'majority' }
  };
  try {
    await session.withTransaction(async () => {
      const coll1 = client.db('mydb1').collection('foo');
      await coll1.updateOne({user_id: 12344,  paid: false }, { $set: { paid: true } } { session });
      // long running computation after this line.
      // what if another query deletes the document inserted above 
      // before this transaction completes.
      await calls_third_party_payment_vendor_api_to_process_payment();
    }, transactionOptions);
 } finally {
    await session.endSession();
    await client.close();
  }
```

What if the update document inside the transaction is simultaneously updated from an outside query before the transaction is committed?

Comment: MongoDB is [ACID](https://www.mongodb.com/basics/acid-transactions) compliant. Also, the limit of a transaction is 60 seconds.

Comment: So will the incoming outside query be queued until the transaction completes?

Answer (score 0):

What you have described is a transaction/operation conflict and

> the operation blocks behind the transaction commit and infinitely retries with backoff logic until `MaxTimeMS` is reached

I wrote a [report](https://github.com/marco-luzzara/mongodb-transaction-simulation/tree/main/doc) on MongoDB transactions, containing some examples in NodeJS too. if you are interested on the subject, I recommend you the paragraphs [WiredTiger Cache](https://github.com/marco-luzzara/mongodb-transaction-simulation/tree/main/doc#wiredtiger-cache) and [What happens when we create a multi-document transaction?](https://github.com/marco-luzzara/mongodb-transaction-simulation/tree/main/doc#what-happens-when-we-create-a-multi-document-transaction)